# Is there a way to set the Android clipboard to null (indicating no items on clipboard)?

Tags: java, android, copy, clipboard, paste

Please read this carefully because similar questions have been asked but this is a new question.

Here's the set up.

First of all I know I can read from the clipboard with the following code (it works great):

```
 private String readClipboard() {
        android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) appContext.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        android.content.ClipData clip = clipboard.getPrimaryClip();
        if (clip != null && clip.getItemCount() > 0) {
            ClipData.Item item = clip.getItemAt(clip.getItemCount() - 1);
            return item.getText().toString();
        }
        return "";

    }
```

Secondly, I have found a way to empty out the item I set on the clipboard with the following (not quite right) code:

```
  private void clearClipboard(){
        android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
         // you can set an empty string or set to null, same result
        //android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText(null,null);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

    }
```

**Does Wipe Previous Item**

That code does set an empty item onto the clipboard so that the previous item is wiped out.

**Does Not Remove Items From Clipboard**

However, that does not actually remove all the items from the clipboard.  That means when the user long-holds on a text box, the system thinks there is an item on the clipboard (even though it is a null or empty string) and it shows up like the following:

[image: paste android clipboard]

**Indicate Nothing On Clipboard**

That's actually incorrect, because **what we really want is all items to be cleared indicating to the user that there is nothing on the clipboard**.

**Google Android API?**

Is there some method in the API that actually clears the Clipboard? I've searched quite a bit and can't find anything, but wonder if I missing it?  Or if the Google API just overlooked this?

Comment: Looking at [the source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/ClipboardManager.java), `setPrimaryClip()` seems to support `null`. Have you tried that?

Comment: @CommonsWare I was just looking at that too.  I am trying it now.  Thanks. I will let you know.  Edit : Tried it.  It still seems to indicate there is an item on the clipboard (the paste menu pops up).

Answer (score 0):

In android dev [copy & paste doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html)

You can check if clipboard is empty with `clipboard.hasPrimaryClip()`

**See this:**
Detect If exist any data in clipboard and check if is text-plain

Gets the ID of the "paste" menu item
`MenuItem mPasteItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_paste);`

If the clipboard doesn't contain data, disable the paste menu item.
If it does contain data, decide if you can handle the data.

```
if (!(clipboard.hasPrimaryClip())) {

    mPasteItem.setEnabled(false);

    } else if (!(clipboard.getPrimaryClipDescription().hasMimeType(MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN))) {

        // This disables the paste menu item, since the clipboard has data but it is not plain text
        mPasteItem.setEnabled(false);
    } else {

        // This enables the paste menu item, since the clipboard contains plain text.
        mPasteItem.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From API 28 on Android we have:

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)
     context.getSystemService(context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE)
```

So

```
clipboard.clearPrimaryClip ()
```

`context` is your own context, is `this` inside your activity